# Does $(x+y)^m=x^m+y^m+z^m$ imply $(x+y+z)^m=(x+z)^m+(y+z)^m$?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, polynomials, integers

Let $x,y,z,m\in\mathbb{N}$, and $x,y,z,m>0$, and also $x>y$.

My problem is to understand if, under these sole hypotheses, we can prove that

> $(x+y)^m=x^m+y^m+z^m \Longrightarrow (x+y+z)^m=(x+z)^m+(y+z)^m.$

*If yes*, how can we prove it?

*If not*, which other hypotheses are needed, in order to make the implication true?

EDIT: I am also interested in the *softer* versions of the statement, i.e. whether we can prove or not that

> $(x+y)^m=x^m+y^m+z^m \Longrightarrow (x+y+z)^m\lessgtr (x+z)^m+(y+z)^m,$

and, if not, which additional conditions we need to make the statement(s) true.

Comment: I am not sure to have correctly tagged this question. In case, can you suggest me the right tags? Thanks!

Comment: For $m=3$ your conditions are not enough, check for example $x=8, y=1, z=6$. On the other hand for $m \neq 3$, it seems that no restrictions on $x,y,z$ are needed, it works for all integers. Well, at least by inspection of small ranges of values...

Comment: @Sil Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding the given condition using binomial we get,

$$ z^m = {m\choose{1}} xy^{m-1} + {m\choose{2}} x^2y^{m-2} +...........+{m\choose{m-1}} x^{m-1}y $$

Now if we expand the claim,  we get,

$$
\sum \frac{m!}{a!b!c!} x^ay^bz^c = z^m + \Bigg( {m\choose{1}} xz^{m-1} + {m\choose{2}} x^2z^{m-2} +...........+{m\choose{m-1}} x^{m-1}z \Bigg)  + \Bigg( {m\choose{1}} yz^{m-1} + {m\choose{2}} y^2z^{m-2} +...........+{m\choose{m-1}} y^{m-1}z \Bigg)
$$

where $a, b, c$ are natural numbers such that $a+b+c = m$ and $a,b,c \neq m$.

We already know the value of $z^m$ so we can substitute that,

$$
\sum \frac{m!}{a!b!c!} x^ay^bz^c = \Bigg(  {m\choose{1}} xy^{m-1} + {m\choose{2}} x^2y^{m-2} +...........+{m\choose{m-1}} x^{m-1}y  \Bigg) + \Bigg( {m\choose{1}} xz^{m-1} + {m\choose{2}} x^2z^{m-2} +...........+{m\choose{m-1}} x^{m-1}z \Bigg)  + \Bigg( {m\choose{1}} yz^{m-1} + {m\choose{2}} y^2z^{m-2} +...........+{m\choose{m-1}} y^{m-1}z \Bigg)
$$

We can simplify this to,

$$
\sum \frac{m!}{a!b!c!} x^ay^bz^c = \Bigg(  {m\choose{1}} ( xy^{m-1} + yz^{m-1} + zx^{m-1} ) +
 {m\choose{2}} (x^2y^{m-2} + y^2z^{m-2} + z^2x^{m-2})...........+{m\choose{m-1}}( x^{m-1}y^ + y^{m-1}z + z^{m-1}x ) \Bigg) 
$$

I can't see how to prove that $LHS=RHS$ from here.  In fact, since you are not sure whether your claim was true, this seems to indicate that the claim is false.

Can anyone try something from here?

**Edit** As the other answer says the claim is clearly contradicting FMT.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the nice work! I have tried to work on this problem with the binomial expansion, but I could not find much (I actually had the impression that this was making the things more complicated!). My suspect is the some other tools (and hypotheses) are needed. However, I will try something from your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't get why the claim is contradicting FMT!

Answer (score 1):

Even without thinking about it, I can tell you that the answer is almost certainly no for $m \ge 3$. Indeed, this would in contradiction with [Fermat's last theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem), if you let $a = x+z$, $b=y+z$, and $c=x+y+z$.

Now it's possible that the implication is still true, because it's possible that there does not exist any $x,y,z$ such that $(x+y)^m = x^m+y^m+z^m$. But a computer helped me find $(1+8)^3 = 1^3 + 8^3 + 6^3$, however $(1+8+6)^3 = 3375$ whereas $(1+6)^3+(1+8)^3 = 3087$.

Comment: Thanks for checking $m=3$ (and to point out the connection with Fermat's theorem). But what about the implication? Do you think that more hypotheses are needed?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt, using the binomial expansion. About the LHS:
$$
x^m+y^m+z^m=(x+y)^m,
$$
$$
x^m+z^m+y^m+z^m=(x+y)^m+z^m,
$$
$$
(x+z)^m+(y+z)^m-\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}z^{m-k}(x^k+y^k)=(x+y+z)^m-\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}z^{m-k}(x+y)^k.
$$
So, here we can isolate the RHS. With the notation of @Najib, we find
$$
c^m-a^m-b^m=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}z^{m-k}[(x+y)^k-x^k-y^k].
$$
$$
\frac{c^m-a^m-b^m}{z^m}=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}\frac{(x+y)^k-x^k-y^k}{z^k}.
$$
On the other hand, the LHS can also be written
$$
z^m=(x+y)^m-x^m-y^m,
$$
$$
z^m=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}x^{m-k}y^k.
$$
$$
\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)^m=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^k...
$$